# Java decompress GZIP stream sequentially

Tags: java, gzip, zlib, chunks

My Java program implements a server that should get a very large file, compressed using gzip, from a client over websockets and should check for some bytes pattern in the file content.

The client sends the file chunks embedded inside a proprietary protocol so I'm getting message after message from the client, parse the message and extract the gzipped file content.

I can't hold the whole file in the program memory so I'm trying to decompress each chunk, process the data and continue to the next chunk.

I'm using the following code:

```
public static String gzipDecompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    String uncompressed;
    try (
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(gis);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter()
    ) {

      char[] buffer = new char[10240];
      for (int length = 0; (length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0; ) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
      uncompressed = writer.toString();
    }

    return uncompressed;
  }
```

But I'm getting the following exception when calling the function with the first compressed chunk:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
```

It's important to mention that I'm not skipping any chunk and trying to decompress the chunks sequentially.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not clear where this data is coming from to start with. You should create one stream that will read *all* the data, and wrap it in a GZipInputStream. It doesn't need to have all the data *in memory*, but it should be a single stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you play with those chunks manually.

The correct way would be to obtain some `InputStream`, wrap it with `GZIPInputStream` and then read the data.

```
    InputStream is = // obtain the original gzip stream

    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(gis);

    //... proceed reading and so on
```

`GZIPInputStream` works in stream fashion, so if you only ask 10kb at a time from your `reader`, the overall memory footprint will be low regardless of the size of the initial GZIP file.

**Update after the question was updated**

A possible solution for your situation is to write an `InputStream` implementation that streams bytes that are being put to it in chunks by your client protocol handler.

Here is a prototype:

```
public class ProtocolDataInputStream extends InputStream {
    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> nextChunks = new ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]>(100);
    private byte[] currentChunk = null;
    private int currentChunkOffset = 0;
    private boolean noMoreChunks = false;

    @Override
    public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
        boolean takeNextChunk = currentChunk == null || currentChunkOffset >= currentChunk.length;
        if (takeNextChunk) {
            if (noMoreChunks) {
                // stream is exhausted
                return -1;
            } else {
                currentChunk = nextChunks.take();
                currentChunkOffset = 0;
            }
        }
        return currentChunk[currentChunkOffset++];
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int available() throws IOException {
        if (currentChunk == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return currentChunk.length - currentChunkOffset;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void addChunk(byte[] chunk, boolean chunkIsLast) {
        nextChunks.add(chunk);
        if (chunkIsLast) {
            noMoreChunks = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Your client protocol handler adds byte chunks using `addChunk()`, while your decompressing code pulls the data out of this stream (via `Reader`).

Please note that this code has some issues:

1. The queue being used has a limited size. If `addChunk()` is being called too frequently, the queue may be filled, which will block `addChunk()`. This may be desirable or not.
2. Only `read()` method is implemented for illustration purposes. For performance, it is better to implement `read(byte[])` in the same manner.
3. Conservative synchornization is used under the assumption that reader (decompressor) and writer (protocol handler calling `addChunk()`) are different threads.
4. `InterruptedException` is not handled on `take()` to avoid too  much details.

If your decompressor and `addChunk()` execute in the same thread (in the same loop), then you could try to use the `InputStream.available()` method when pulling using `InputStream` or `Reader.ready()` when pulling with a `Reader`.

Comment: Can't I use ByteArrayInputStream or other InputStream that wrap byte array as the InputStream I'm passing to GZIPInputStream? In my situation, I can't really use the original InputSteam that get's the data from the server.

Comment: Why can't you use the original `InputStream`? The only safe way to feed `GZIPInputStream` with bytes that I know of is to read all the bytes into memory first, which is not what you want with a big file.

Comment: I added details to better describe the situation, I'm getting the file chunks embedded inside a proprietary protocol so my InputStream gets a full protocol message, parse it and then extract the file chunks from it and only then can decompress the chunk, I don't control the client and don't know when the next message that contains the next file chunk will arrive. thanks and sorry for the bad description.

Answer (score 2):

An arbitrary sequence of bytes from a gzipped stream is not valid standalone gzip data.  One way or another, you must concatenate all the byte chunks.

The easiest way is to accumulate them all with a simple pipe:

```
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class ChunkInflater {
    private final PipedOutputStream pipe;

    private final InputStream stream;

    public ChunkInflater()
    throws IOException {
        pipe = new PipedOutputStream();
        stream = new GZIPInputStream(new PipedInputStream(pipe));
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    public void addChunk(byte[] compressedChunk)
    throws IOException {
        pipe.write(compressedChunk);
    }
}
```

Now you have an InputStream you can read in whatever increments you desire.  For instance:

```
ChunkInflater inflater = new ChunkInflater();

Callable<Void> chunkReader = new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call()
    throws IOException {
        byte[] chunk;
        while ((chunk = readChunkFromSource()) != null) {
            inflater.addChunk(chunk);
        }

        return null;
    }
};
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(chunkReader);
executor.shutdown();

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inflater.getInputStream());
// read text here
```